# .Net UDP packet loss though all packets arrive (Wireshark) - ReceiveBuffer not the issue

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, udp

This is the same question as [C# UDP packetloss though all packets arrive (WireShark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076686), except I do set `ReceiverBuffer` to 10MB, and I also monitor `Socket.Available` which shows the buffer doesn't even reach 200k utilization.

In a simple test case, sending the same small (multicast) UDP packet (net data size: 137) 25,000 times using tcpreplay with at rate of 40Mbps, oftentimes not all packets arrive in my program, although all packets arrive in Wireshark, which I run at the same time on that box. Sometimes it's only one packet that's missing, sometimes it's about a dozen, sometimes more.

**The Code**

```
static void Main()
{
    int udpPacketsReceived = 0;
    var bindAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.20.54");
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 10485760; // 10M

    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(bindAddress, 51001));
    socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("239.193.1.1")));
    Console.WriteLine("Effective ReceiveBuffer size: " + socket.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveBuffer));

    var t = new Thread(ipAndClient =>
    {
        var buffer = new byte[2000];
        int maxAvail = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            socket.Receive(buffer);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref udpPacketsReceived);
            var available = socket.Available;
            if (available > maxAvail)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("available new max: " + available);
                maxAvail = available;
            }
        }
    });
    t.Start();
    int lastValue = -1;
    while (true)
    {
        var newValue = Thread.VolatileRead(ref udpPacketsReceived);
        if (newValue != lastValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total UDP packets received: {0}", newValue);
            lastValue = newValue;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Example output**

```
Effective ReceiveBuffer size: 10485760
Total UDP packets received: 0
available new max: 685
available new max: 3288
available new max: 3836
available new max: 6165
available new max: 8220
available new max: 10960
Total UDP packets received: 14307
available new max: 18632
available new max: 140425
available new max: 141521
available new max: 143439
Total UDP packets received: 24996
```

What's wrong?

**Important addition** (which proved crucial in hindsight, see [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26581275/709537)): I'm running on a Windows guest in a VirtualBox host, using a **"bridged" virtual network card**.

Comment: Read the bufffersize back and output it to ensure that the OS has actually let you have all that kernel space. Also, receiving all those little datagrams very quickly means a lot of driver signaling because each datagram has to be returned individually - a lot of work.  Besides - it's UDP so who cares?

Comment: @MartinJames I added the check and updated my question. The setting seems to be fine. Why I care about an efficient socket implementation, i.e. one that does not necessitate resends for packets that did arrive? Because I haven't implemeneted resends, as the environment is effectively local, and there just are no drops - except those of MS' socket implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steffen Ullrich's answer and comments lead me to dig deeper into the setup of my system - Windows 8.1 running in a VirtualBox - and I found that for my workloads, which max at around 50Mbps and 20kpps, I could **get rid of all packet drops by changing the virtual network card from "bridged" to "[Paravirtualized network adapter (virtio-net)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)"**.

This necessitates installing network drivers in the Windows guest. Drivers, which can be downloaded via http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers. The easiest way to get binary, digitally signed drivers is to click the "[Fedora](http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/)" link on that page, and install "netkvm.inf", which is the *Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter* driver, for your OS.

Comment: What was the reason behind it that it start working after changing the virtual network card type?
I am facing similar issue but could not be able to figure out the solution yet. could you provide some points I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark gets the packets before they get passed to the protocol stack, while the receive buffer is at the end of the in-kernel protocol stack. There is a lot of memory allocation and other processing going on and on high loads it might simply drop some packets before they reach the receive buffer.

Here's what [MS support had to say](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/35f79821-7ab5-4335-89d5-cec58fa31d33/detecting-the-amount-of-udp-packet-loss):

> Winsock layer sits on top of the transport layer. Datagrams may be dropped at various layers within the networking stack.

Comment: So you think it might be happening somewhere at the OS level. Do you happen to have a pointer handy where I can read up on this?

Comment: Not really a single reference, but this is how network stacks usually work, not  only on windows. As for windows I've found some quoted information from MS in the last message of https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/35f79821-7ab5-4335-89d5-cec58fa31d33/detecting-the-amount-of-udp-packet-loss: "...Datagrams may be dropped at various layers within the networking stack...."

Comment: Thanks Steffen, that's helpful. I wonder whether there's any way to make it drop less packets...

Comment: Network stack tuning is really hard science and I'm no expert in it. But performance is influenced by the network card, the driver, available memory, CPU performance, system and application architecture etc. But, if your main problem is that you are loosing packets than I would recommend to either simply use TCP which automatically tunes itself to the rate the system can securely receive packets. Or you have to implement similar measures yourself, that is reduce the senders speed on packet loss.

Comment: If you don't want to move away from UDP remember, that UDP is explicitly defined as an unreliable protocol and packets can be dropped whenever more important things need to be done. So don't count on the OS kernel to preserve the packets for you.

Comment: Agree, UDP is unreliable. We are receiving real time multicast traffic that cannot be throttled. The server in question also listens on a TCP port where we could request missing packets over a reliable protocol - which is something we haven't implemented and I would like to know how far we can get with the current implementation. I'm rewriting this whole thing so the next version will use PGM for efficient and reliable multicast transfer. No need for manual fiddling in the app layer using TCP etc.

Comment: Interesting design. It is definitely hard to have the benefits of multicast but still have reliable transport for all recipients.

Comment: That's what's PGM is for. It's a great protocol for that purpose, really well thought out. Even when scaling to hundreds of thousands of clients.