# C# udp server not reading fast enough

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

```
public class RCon
{
    static readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> ReceivedPacketQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
    static IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.XXX.XX.117"), 2222); 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new UdpClient
                         {
                             ExclusiveAddressUse = false,
                             Client = { ReceiveBufferSize = 8192 }
                          };

        client.Client.Bind(_ipEndPoint);
        client.BeginReceive(OnUdpData, client);

        var message = new byte[100];
        int numberOfPackets ;

        for (numberOfPackets = 0; numberOfPackets < 84; numberOfPackets++)
        {
             client.Send(message, message.Length, _ipEndPoint);
        }
    }

    static void OnUdpData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
        var message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref _ipEndPoint);
        ReceivedPacketQueue.Enqueue(message);
        socket.BeginReceive(OnUdpData, socket);
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple program that sends packets of 100 bytes and the same machine as server receives packets asynchronously and stores in queue. Packets received is fine until number of packets are 83 Once I start increasing the number of packets more than 84 the rate of packets received falls through. As I understand this is because the client is not fast enough in reading the incoming packets and as the buffer overflows the packets are being lost. Is there any way that I can make server fast enough to receive the fast incoming packets.

There was similar question [C# UDP packetloss though all packets arrive (WireShark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076686/c-sharp-udp-packetloss-though-all-packets-arrive-wireshark) I think I am doing what the answer was suggested but still the issue persists.

Comment: Looks like you send messages to yourself - from ip 10.170.25.117:2222 to ip 10.170.25.117:222, and actually i don't know how it will work in this situation

Try to set both send and receive buffers to the max value, i.e. 65536

Comment: Thanks Dmitry . Yes same machine is acting as Server and Client. Even if I set to maximum buffer size and increase the rate of packets (from 84 to 1200 or bigger number)I start loosing packets as reading isn't quick enough and over flow buffer happens. My question is there anything that can I improve the async begin receive (OnUdpData) code in any way to fasten reading the packets.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it uses the same ip at the same port for both server and client:)

I did a test with your code. I have added 2 static vars
static int sendIter = 0;
static int recvIter = 0;

and run the app. It exits with sendIter = 84 and recvIter = 0..2-3 iterations

I think it happens because you begin async operation(BeginReceive) in the function and then immediately start for loop to send msgs.
Under the hood BeginReceive starts the thread, but it has no chances to switch context to itself even if it's ready to process incoming message because of this for loop - it takes all cpu time.

Then i have added Thread.Sleep(1)(it will allow the app to switch thread context) right after client.Send and i got sendIter and recvIter equal

So i think the client is fast enough if it has cpu time

```
class Program
{
    static readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> ReceivedPacketQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
    static IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.4.142"), 2222);
    static int sendIter = 0;
    static int recvIter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new UdpClient
        {
            ExclusiveAddressUse = false,
            Client = { ReceiveBufferSize = 8192 }
        };

        client.Client.Bind(_ipEndPoint);
        client.BeginReceive(OnUdpData, client);

        var message = new byte[100];
        int numberOfPackets;

        for (numberOfPackets = 0; numberOfPackets < 100; numberOfPackets++)
        {
            client.Send(message, message.Length, _ipEndPoint);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            sendIter++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sendIter);
        Console.WriteLine(recvIter);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void OnUdpData(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
        var message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref _ipEndPoint);
        ReceivedPacketQueue.Enqueue(message);
        recvIter++;
        socket.BeginReceive(OnUdpData, socket);
    }
}
```